# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.6.1 Install Repository and sync project Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deegi.lab10"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

this is sync errror : `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.6.1`

> build error: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.6.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:

my emulator play services version is : 11.3.02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.6.1` **doesn't exist**.

Use:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

Comment: Besides, add in the file build.gradle (Module: app) minSdkVersion 15. That resolved my problems.